# Android - Programmatically making a StateListDrawable, overwriting previous one?

Tags: android, xml, statelistdrawable

I need to make a StateListDrawable programmatically over and over again (when ever the user selects a button). However, I'm afraid of generating new XML files each time this happens. How can I make sure the previous XML file is getting destroyed and/or replaced?

My code, as of now:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_tap_state));
states.addState(new int[]{}, new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), newItem));
item.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Comment: Do you need any more help? If it was useful please mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, if you create a StateListDreawable object programmatically, it won't generate xml files. Your code is perfect if you want just adding states to your state list drawable.